# Why innerHTML return null

Tags: javascript, html

I need div to show an user's message, where is : `[name] : [text of message]`, and when I click the button to send it, message should be shown in 
appropriate div. But when I write a message and click the button, than I see in div: `null : null`. Why it happens?

I have alredy tried to change name of variable and name of div's id that contains name and text.

**HTML:**

```
<form class="login" onsubmit="return false">
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="name"><br>
    <textarea type="text" id="message" placeholder="message"> 
    </textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" id="btn" value="Send">
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var chat = document.getElementById('chat'); //chat
var name = document.getElementById('name'); //username
var message = document.getElementById('message'); //message 
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.onclick = function(){
    chat.innerHTML = name + " : " + message;
}
```

Comment: You probably want to use .value to get the value of the textboxes

Comment: Also if the code you posted appears in a `<script>` block at the top of the page, it won't work because the elements will not be part of the DOM when the script runs.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read this guide on [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2):

You have not put `.value` to get value of `input` . Try like below :

```js
btn.onclick = function(){
var chat = document.getElementById('chat'); //chat
var name = document.getElementById('name').value; //username
var message = document.getElementById('message').value; //message 
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
    chat.innerHTML = name + " : " + message;
}
```

```html
<form class="login" onsubmit="return false">
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="name"><br>
    <textarea type="text" id="message" placeholder="message"> 
    </textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" id="btn" value="Send">
</form>

<div id="chat">
</div>
```